# Typescript tuple lint error not consistent [vscode]

Tags: javascript, typescript

Following along with [this great video](https://youtu.be/ahCwqrYpIuM?t=597) on how to use types in typescript.

But I notice an inconsistency with my text editor's linting and the video.

The video shows like this

[image]

And mine shows like this

[image]

[image]

If I change the code, so it should not lint any errors, I still get the errors

[image]

What is going on here?

Don't know if this matter but I'm on typescript 3.3.x and the video is on 3.1.x

Comment: Do not include your code in image form

Comment: @Patrick I normally don't do. But had to in this instance to show where the lint occurred.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video declared the array as follows:

```
const arr: myList = []
```

And you declared it like that:

```
const arr: myList[] = []
```